# What is difference between OnChange and AddOnChange in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

In CRM 2011, i wrote a function in js and attached that function to OnChange event of a field. When the value changed in LookUpField1, it should update value of another LookUpField2 but it is only updating after saving and loading the form.

Where as if i use addonChange and firing the function, LookUpField2 value is automatically updating when LookUpField1 is changed.

Why is it working with addonChange and not OnChange event of attr?

Apart from programmatically firing a function using addonChange, are there any instances where we need to use addonchange?

I hope i make sense ;) & Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should show the code of your function. Since you seem to update a Lookup field, I suspect you set an EntityReference which only contains the LogicalName and the Id value but not the visible Name attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OnChange is the event. addOnChange is the way to add a handler Here's what the documentation says:

> **OnChange Event**
>
> Use the addOnChange, removeOnChange, and fireOnChange
> methods and to manage event handlers for the OnChange event.

Please see the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409(v=crm.5).aspx